# xxxChanged methods dont' get called in JavaScript

Tags: custom-controls, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, shadow-dom

- I have two packages with several polymer custom elements.
- Each package imports the other

  - One package contains elements that use or derive from the elements in the other package.
  - The other package uses the elements from the imported package just in the demo pages to make them more appealing. 
    There are no circular dependencies between elements.
- In each package I have a folder 'example' that contains a demo page for each custom element.
- I use the transformers configuration in pubspec.yaml and pub build to build the Javascript version of the demo pages.
  (Because pub build doesn't yet support the example directory for entry points I created a symbolic link web that points to examples.)
- When I execute pub build the examples are built and several of them work fine.
  Not all though because there are limitations with transformers:

pub build with transformers doesn't support imported packages that have transformers configured in pubspec.yaml.

So my new approach was as suggested at the Dart web-ui group

- I created a new package
- The new package imports the two packages with the custom elements.
- I symlinked all example files from the two custom elements packages to the web/ and web/src directory of the new package.

When I execute pub build all seems fine but
when I open the demo pages and debug them I see **none of the `xxxChanged` methods of any of the custom elements get called** (except when they are called explicitly from <del>enteredView</del> `attached` or `ready`).
Other methods like <del>enteredView</del> `attached` or `ready` are called though.

A diff between the files (about 14k size) showed several smaller differences but the most (about 98%) are equal.
This generated code (not minified) is not easy to decipher at least not for me and I found no hint what could have caused these differences.

Any Idea what can be the source of that problem?

Comment: I tried copying the files instead of symlinking but that also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
```

(without any entry_points)
to the pubspec.yaml of the custom elements packages all works fine in JavaScript too.

**EDIT**

related issues

- [generated JavaScript for polymer elements dosn't call xxxChanged for published attributes](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15080)
- [add support for global transformers in code_transformers](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18489)
- [polymer transformer can only be used on the application package and not on a library package](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15038)
- [add support for dev_transformers](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14187)